# How to hide nextjs API routes from being directly accessible through URL?

Tags: javascript, security, next.js

Is there any way to make next.js API routes response data hidden when accessing it through URL? I want to hide the routes because there is some data I don't want to be directly accessed by the user.

Comment: I dont think this question in tightly related to next.js, by the way you can just make your call with POST instead GET

Comment: You can't "hide" the api endpoint, since your client app is accessing => it is revealed to the user.

You need to protect the api endpoint with one of the many ways. one of them is to send a special accessToken which the server returned to you before.

Comment: I am doing API call using POST request only but there is data present in the API URL.

Comment: @felixmosh Is there any reference for the same to protect the API endpoint?

Comment: It is a matter of simple authentication, https://github.com/nextauthjs/next-auth-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to hide API routes from users through url in nextjs. In fact, nextjs API routes are publically available to anyone when you host the website without exporting and hosting from out folder. I ended making server-side routes using node express and then connected to the frontend in nextjs.

Comment: In this way you are going to lose all the pre-render features, am I wrong?

Answer (score 9):

In Next.js version 13 you can use middleware to stuck the user from directly checking the route of your api by checking the req.referer then only your app can call and api of your app. Auth token can also be use inside middleware.

https://nextjs.org/blog/next-13-1#nextjs-advanced-middleware

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

import type { NextRequest } from 'next/server'

export function middleware(req: NextRequest) {

    const url = req.nextUrl
    const { pathname } = url

    if (pathname.startsWith(`/api/`)) {
        if (!req.headers.get("referer")?.includes(process.env.APP_URL as string)) {
        return NextResponse.json({ message: 'Unauthorized' }, { status: 401 });
        }
      }

     return NextResponse.next()

}

export const config = {
  matcher: ['/((?!_next|fonts|examples|svg|[\\w-]+\\.\\w+).*)'],
}
```

process.env.APP_URL is the url of your app for example : http://localhost:3000

Comment: `APP_URL` would need to be set up in advance. Also, this doesn't work if the user uses cURL or Postman and passes a `referer`.

Answer (score 2):

Probably quick & simple way to protect the [API routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction) is through the stateless session management libraries like [`iron-session`](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session) with [save / creation](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session#sessionsave) and [destroy](https://github.com/vvo/iron-session#sessiondestroy) endpoints to validate and invalidate the [Next JS api routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-routes/introduction)

Try this [github example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-iron-session/) by Vercel. This might a be good starting point.

> **Remember:** *Always use a best authentication mechanism to protect any direct api route call with appropriate privileges in place. [DYOR](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dyor)*

Answer (score 1):

You can set an authorization header that checks auth key everytime user access that API, that way normal user wont be able to access the page without knowing the auth key

Answer (score 0):

It is extremely unworthy effort to hide API routes. and for protecting essential  data in API..there is CORS and Authentication methods can prevent noicy unwanted traffic I found brilliant blog on this

https://dev.to/a7u/how-to-protect-nextjs-api-routes-from-other-browsers-3838

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31709716)

Comment: I don't think this is a good answer. The method used on the linked page just requires someone to amend a header to bypass cors.

Comment: @jrswgtr the link is already not working.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by implementing a secret token that you pass in the headers of each request to the api and you can in the backend check if the token is not here you can display another message to the user

Comment: Request headers are shown in the Network tab.

Answer (score 0):

I have searched a lot for the proper way. But it seems only solution is to use Nginx as reverse proxy server which can hide the api routes and only allow selected routes.